# Docker Production Env WSL2 vs Linux

Tags: linux, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have been trying to find a definite resource that can answer this question, but haven't hit on it so far.

Scenario:
Company A has been been running 'Windows docker containers' on 'Windows hosts' until now and would like to switch over to Linux. However due to circumstances (politics, culture, resources...etc.), there has been resistance. The compromise that was put forward was:

- The containers would run on Linux - so developers get what they want
- The Host would run Windows - so IT gets what they want

From what I see WSL2 seems to be the current 'premier' way of achieving the above.

However I have not seen any documentation anywhere on how production-ready WSL2 is.  Is WSL2 suitable to run in production for this type of scenario?   Or should we plan on running Linux containers on Linux hosts?  Or is there some other way of reliably achieving Linux containers on Windows hosts in production?

Example use-case: Spring Boot app inside a Linux (Centos7) Docker container, running on Windows Server 2022 with Ubuntu 22 WSL2, with volume mounting between host and container to expose properties files.

Comment: On docker's site there is a how-to on how to install Docker For Windows (in Windows) and make it available in WSL for the usual Linux docker commands and whatnot: https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/wsl/ That being said, Docker for windows can run linux containers natively without needing WSL environment, so unless you are also using a CI/CD build/deploy platform that needs to speak linux to the deploy server, then WSL may not be necessary for this work.

Comment: @JNevill, could you elaborate further on the: "Docker for windows can run linux containers natively without needing WSL environment"?....that is definitely closer to what I am looking for

Comment: What I'm saying is that if you are wanting to build a linux docker container on your local machine but have a windows machine run the built image, you can do that in `docker for windows` on that machine without WSL. If you install Docker for Windows there is an option to switch it between Linux and Windows containers. It can only do one or the other though, if memory serves. So you can't run a windows and a linux image on the same machine. I'm a little rusty on this subject though, so best to verify on docker's documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Docker Desktop with WSL2 should not be considered a production-ready environment, especially in an enterprise environment.  While I'm a huge proponent of WSL2, it is designed primarily for end-users (developer/sysadmin/CLI-user).

Microsoft makes this fairly (but not crystal) clear in the [WSL FAQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-use-wsl-for-production-scenarios--):

> #### Can I use WSL for production scenarios?
>
> WSL has been designed and built to use with inner loop development workflows. There are design features in WSL that make it great for this purpose but may make it challenging for production-related scenarios compared to other products. Our goal is to make clear how WSL differs from a regular VM environment, so you can make the decision on whether it fits your business needs.

They then go on to list some differences, but several of the more critical ones that would impact Docker enterprise use:

- The Linux kernel is updated automatically with WSL2 itself.  While you can build your own kernel, this isn't a typical enterprise scenario, of course.
- WSL2 runs as a *user* level application.  It cannot start without the user being logged into the Windows *Desktop*.  This does not make it suitable for Server applications where a hands-off approach is needed.

While I don't have any confirmation of this, I doubt that either Microsoft or Docker would provide support under your enterprise agreements for WSL2 running in a production Windows Server/Docker Desktop environment.  Of course, if you have any intention of really investigating this, *that's* the question you should be asking (of Microsoft and/or Docker) as that answer will be more critical than Stack Overflow Developer expertise (and/or opinions).

Comment: WSL 2 is now shipped with Windows Server, which is not a desktop OS, so I believe it is a sign that WSL 2 fits containerized applications for UAT / Production environments. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/itops-talk-blog/wsl2-now-available-on-windows-server-2022/ba-p/3447570

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez Running WSL2 in Windows Server has been an option for a while (It was available in Server 2019 before that).  That's actually what the question was asking about, and what I answered.  As I mentioned, *"I doubt that either Microsoft or Docker would provide support under your enterprise agreements for WSL2 running in a production **Windows Server** / Docker Desktop environment."* (emphasis added).  I feel they'd still point to the WSL FAQ that says, *"may make it challenging"* -- That's likely just Marketing-speak for saying *"Not supported"* ;-)

Comment: My understanding is that WSL FAQ "may make it challenging" refers to WSL 1 and that statement does not apply to WSL 2. The fact that an actual Linux kernel is part of WSL 2 and it runs over Hyper-V, means it should behave exactly as any other Linux VM.

Comment: @JoseManuelGomezAlvarez I *wish* I could find a way to agree with you here, since I'd love to see WSL2 on Windows Server available as a production option, but if you read the bullet points under that *"challenging"* statement, it *definitely* applies to WSL2.  WSL1 doesn't use a Linux kernel, nor does it have GPU access (both of which are referenced in that FAQ section).  Today's reality is that WSL2 **is** WSL from Microsoft's perspective.  While WSL1 is still "supported", it hasn't been updated (not even a single bug fix, that I can find) in almost 2 years now.